# Getting error while setting spark.ext.h2o.backend.cluster.mode=external in pysparkling standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark, h2o, sparkling-water

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pysparkling import *
import h2o
from pysparkling.ml import H2OAutoML
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkApplication').getOrCreate()
hc = H2OContext.getOrCreate()
```

Spark-submit Command:

> spark-submit --master spark://local:7077 --py-files
> sparkling-water-3.36.1.3-1-3.2/py/h2o_pysparkling_3.2-3.36.1.3-1-3.2.zip
> --conf "spark.ext.h2o.backend.cluster.mode=external" --conf spark.ext.h2o.external.start.mode="auto" --conf
> spark.ext.h2o.external.h2o.driver="/home/whiz/spark/h2odriver-3.36.1.3.jar"
> --conf spark.ext.h2o.external.cluster.size=2 spark_h20/h2o_script.py

Error Logs:
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o58.getOrCreate.
: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hadoop": error=2, No such file or directory**

Answer (score 0):

the automatic start of SW external backend is only support in Hadoop or K8s environments. In a standalone deployment, you need to deploy the external backend manually according to [the tutorial in SW documentation](https://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/3.2/latest-stable/doc/deployment/backends.html?highlight=external%20backend#manual-mode-of-external-backend-without-hadoop-standalone).

Comment: While trying to run using this, I got this following error:    #2319  1654622-15  WARN water.default: ERROR MESSAGE:
08-08 19:40:17.287 10.255.11.32:54321    #2319  1654622-15  WARN water.default: 
08-08 19:40:17.288 10.255.11.32:54321    #2319  1654622-15  WARN water.default: Resource /3/verifyWebOpen not found

Comment: Can you share logs from H2O nodes. By default, they are stored to `h2ologs` folder in user home directory on each server.